# Keep getting Internal server error randomly

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda

My lambdas crash randomly. I get a response half the time, and half the time I get Internal server error. Its very strange behavior. Im not sure if its some sort of a cold start time out?

```js
import { ValidationError, validate } from 'class-validator'
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer'
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent } from 'aws-lambda'
import { AssetAdditionValidation } from '../../validation/AssetAdditionValidation'
import { Asset, createAsset } from '../../db/entities/Asset' 
import { ValidationErrorArray } from '../../utilities/errorClass'

export async function addAsset(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent) {
    try {
        if (event.body === null) {
            throw new Error('Missing body')
        }
        const assetData = JSON.parse(event.body)
        const asset = plainToInstance(AssetAdditionValidation, assetData)

        const validationErrors = await validate(asset)
        if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
            const formattedErrors = validationErrors.map(
                (err: ValidationError) => {
                    return {
                        property: err.property,
                        messages: Object.values(err.constraints || {}),
                    }
                }
            )
            throw new ValidationErrorArray(formattedErrors)
        }

        const {
            organizationId,
            assetType,
            assetTag,
            manufacturer,
            model,
            serialNumber,
            operatingSystem,
        } = JSON.parse(event.body)

        const assetClass = new Asset(
            organizationId,
            assetType,
            assetTag,
            manufacturer,
            model,
            serialNumber,
            operatingSystem
        )

        const newAsset = await createAsset(organizationId, assetClass)

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            // body: JSON.stringify({ asset: 'hello' }),
            body: JSON.stringify({ asset: newAsset }),
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        if (error instanceof ValidationErrorArray) {
            return {
                statusCode: 400,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    validationErrors: error.validationErrors,
                }),
            }
        } else {
            return {
                statusCode: error.statusCode || 500,
                body: JSON.stringify({ message: error.message }),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also when I check the CloudWatch logs there are no errors. Also I want to mention when I run the code locally from my vscode to test things out it works, but when I access the API from postman I get this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that I was using

runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X

when I switched to

runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X

it worked just fine!